# How does Screencastify Chrome App work?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, screen-capture, webm, screencast

I need to develop something similar, but all I've got so far is a Chrome app which uses Whammy.js for encode de webm images from a `desktopCapture` stream and encode them to a .webm video, but it is extremely slow (almost 5 minutes for 30 seconds) and I can't record the system sound.

I tested this Screencastify app and I think it does a pretty decent job, it records even in fullHd fast and also can record the system sound. But how does this work? AFAIK Chrome doesn't have an API for recording the system sound and encode video that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Screencastify uses [Native Client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client).

Comment: Can you expand your answer _just a bit_? Even if correct, it looks bad.

Comment: Sorry, but that's all I know about it.